# Express $y = KC^x$ as a linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, exponential-function

Consider an exponential relationship of the form $y = KC^x$ where $K$ and $C$ are constants.

Express the exponential function $y = KC^x$ as a linear function and describe how you would obtain the coefficients $K$ and $C$ from the linear equation of best fit. Note that you do not need to enter anything onto Excel, just describe mathematically.

Comment: Hint: $\ln y=\ln K+(\ln C)x$.

Comment: 1. $y = KC^x$
2. $ln y = x ln KC$
3. $ln y = x ln K + ln C$
4. $(ln y - ln C) / x = ln K$

(1 to 4 are the steps so if i've made a mistake its easier to refer to)
Is this correct so far? My next move would be to isolate K so K= ....

Not sure what to do next.. Perhaps..
5. $K = e^((ln y - ln C) / x)

Yes, no??

Comment: I will write a comment or answer in a few hours. Apologies about the delay.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that $y$ is always positive. Let $z$ be the logarithm of $y$. Which base? It does not matter. I will use the natural logarithm $\ln$, but others might use the logarithm to the base $10$.

Note that if $y=KC^x$ then $z=\ln y=\ln K+(\ln C)x$.

Suppose that we are given values $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n$ of $x$, and the associated values $y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n$ of $y$. These might be two columns in a spreadsheet. Calculate the values $z_1=\ln(y_1), z_2=\ln(y_2), \dots, z_n=\ln(y_n)$.

If the $y_i$ are (approximately) related to the $x_i$ by $y_i=KC^{x_i}$, then we have, *approximately*, 
$$z_i=\ln K+(\ln C)x_i.$$
This is a linear relationship. Use the usual method to find the line of best fit $z=a+bx$ to the data $(x_i,z_i)$, that is, $(x_i,\ln(y_i))$.

Then our estimate for $\ln K$ will be given by $a$, meaning that our estimate for $K$ is $K=e^a$. Similarly, our estimate for $C$ is given by $C=e^b$.

If instead we use $z_i=\log_{10}(x_i)$, the analyis is much that same, except that at the end we use $K=10^a$ and $C=10^b$.

Comment: $K = e^a = e^((-ln C)xi)$    ???

Comment: @Zantheor: The first equation is right. The second is not. We want $\ln C=b$ so $C=e^b$.  No $x_i$.

Comment: That didn't quiet format correctly for me.. But a = (- ln C)xi..??

Comment: How do I write that though without the b variation, with the lettering etc used from the start of the post? I need to be able to show my working out

Comment: I showed the working out in detail, apart from the finding of $a$ and $b$, which is obtained by finding the line of best fit to the set of points $(x_i,\ln(x_i))$. Then I showed how, once we have found $a$ and $b$, we find $K$ and $C$. That's what the question asked for.

Comment: I apologies, I'm still studying mathematics and my skills are still only at an intermediate level so I don't 100% understand the answer. I get the idea of it well enough,  but not well enough to be able to put pen to paper and make the equations look like my own.   It makes sense until it gets to z = a + bx . I get that this is a formula, but I don't exactly see what a equals and what b equals. Without knowing that it's difficult for me to accurately just what K and C exactly equal

Comment: To further explain what I mean, I'm use to seeing exactly what happens to each letter number variable etc... Because they've been turned into variables I am a little lost as to where they have ended up

Comment: There are various ways to get "the line of best fit" to the data $(x_i,\ln(y_i))$. But there is a most standard one. My reading of the question is that one is not asked to supply the formula, just to describe how to get $K$ and $L$ from the formula. That's what I did. But if you want a formula for the coefficients that I canned $a$ and $b$, you can find it by googling line of best fit. If you have trouble I can find the link for you.